# Add restriction conditionally

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have very complex criteria. Let's see the following criteria:

```
         new List < ICriterion > {
            Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Name", user.Name)),
            Restrictions.Or(
               Restrictions.And(
                  Restrictions.And(                 
                     Restrictions.Eq("Status", user.Status))
                     ...
                ))
                ...
         };
```

but I need to add one restriction conditionally in depend on one setting.

```
    if(Setting.SomeSettings)
        {
           new List < ICriterion > {
                    Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Name", user.Name)),
                    Restrictions.Or(
                       Restrictions.And(
                          Restrictions.And(
                            **//new restriction**
                             Restrictions.Eq("Some", user.Some))
                             Restrictions.Eq("Status", user.Status))
                             ...
                        ))
                        ...
                 };
        }
        else
        {
           new List < ICriterion > {
                    Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Name", user.Name)),
                    Restrictions.Or(
                       Restrictions.And(
                          Restrictions.And(                 
                             Restrictions.Eq("Status", user.Status))
                             ...
                        ))
                        ...
                 };
        }
```

How to avoid this duplication?

Comment: Honestly, this seems to be just an exercise in C#... Just create the list first, do common stuff and in **if** condition add what needed

Comment: Yes, it's the first solution what come to mind. But, I think it's a very popular task. And, I hope there are some extension methods or something should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take out the condition as a variable and use it, something like,

```
         ICriterion criterion;

         if(Setting.SomeSettings)    
         {
           criterion = Restrictions.And(
                            **//new restriction**
                             Restrictions.Eq("Some", user.Some))
                             Restrictions.Eq("Status", user.Status))
                             ...
                        ));
        }
        else
        {
           criterion = Restrictions.And(
                          Restrictions.And(                 
                             Restrictions.Eq("Status", user.Status))
                             ...
                        ));
        }

        new List < ICriterion > {
                    Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Name", user.Name)),
                    Restrictions.Or(
                       Restrictions.And(
                        criterion   
                        ...
                 };
```

Comment: I think it's one possible solution. I hope there are ways to build it dynamically maybe.